# regenerate wordpress version.php

Tags: wordpress, version

Don't ask me how but I just did a huge mistake, and I need to regenerate the version.php file in wordpress.

Do you know if there is a way do to that, or another way to get the current wp version without this file ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please refrain from swearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download a new version of [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/download/)

and take the original version.php file

(is this)

```
<?php
/**
* The WordPress version string
*
* @global string $wp_version
*/
$wp_version = '3.8.1';

/**
* Holds the WordPress DB revision, increments when changes are made to the WordPress DB      schema.
*
* @global int $wp_db_version
*/
$wp_db_version = 26691;

/**
* Holds the TinyMCE version
*
* @global string $tinymce_version
*/
$tinymce_version = '359-20131026';

/**
* Holds the required PHP version
*
* @global string $required_php_version
*/
$required_php_version = '5.2.4';

/**
* Holds the required MySQL version
*
* @global string $required_mysql_version
*/
$required_mysql_version = '5.0';
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to know the current version (old install). If i do that, it will just tell me 3.8.1...

Comment: you can no longer get into the admin panel of wordpress?

Comment: Yes i can. Nothing seems to have changed. But even in the admin I have no trace of the current version, I hoped that it was stored another place...

Comment: try to search this metatag <meta name="generator" content="WordPress vx.x.x" /> on your page

Comment: It's empty... I think every version display take the value in version.php.

Comment: Wow, this is interesting, do you know if this file is always updated or if it's just the main version ? Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: if the answer has solved your problem "accept it", so help the other users :)